# Do any ios graphics libraries have built-in 'explosion' effects?

Tags: iphone, ios, graphics, core-image

Given a UIImage, I'd like to "explode" it into a bunch of little pieces as a cute animation. Letterpress has something like this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Explosions are *so* 2011. All the cool kids use star wipes now.

Comment: Look at CAEmitterLayer - but you'd need to divide the image up into pieces for each particle. AFAIK letterpress is written, apparently just for giggles, without using UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

For 3D effects, you should use OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library available to do this now. Its MIT licenced too.
You can grab it here: https://github.com/vibrazy/letterpressexplosion